# What is a Rotting Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Rotting Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Rotting Words™ | Not Rotting Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| admin | job |
| box | tube |
| dawn | sleep |
| elm | river |
| fang | stun |
| fusion | bomb |
| lean | wheel |
| opal | spots |
| open | hotel |
| pawn | bug |

**What is the special rule that Rotting Words™ conform to?**

**What is special about the Not Rotting Words™?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Rotting Word:

> Becomes another English word when rot-x is applied, where 'x' is the length of the word itself.
>
>  *(NB 'rot-x' is shorthand for a Caesar shift of 'x' positions onward through the alphabet...)*

Like follows:

> admin -- rot-5 --> **firns**
>  box -- rot-3 --> **era**
>  dawn -- rot-4 --> **hear**
>  elm -- rot-3 --> **hop**
>  fang -- rot-4 --> **jerk**
>  fusion -- rot-6 --> **layout**
>  lean -- rot-4 --> **pier**
>  opal -- rot-4 --> **step**
>  open -- rot-4 --> **stir**
>  pawn -- rot-4 --> **tear**
>
>  Note that while most of these are common English words, '[firns](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/firn#English)' refers to snow that has gone through multiple thaw-and-refreeze cycles.

As for the Not Rotting Words:

> All of these *do* still form real words when a Caesar shift is applied, but in these cases the value of the shift is *not* equal to the length of the word itself:
>
>  job -- rot-12 --> *van*
>  tube -- rot-14 --> *hips*
>  sleep -- rot-9 --> *bunny*
>  river --rot-9 --> *arena*
>  stun -- rot-11 --> *defy*
>  bomb -- rot-6 --> *hush*
>  wheel -- rot-7 --> *dolls*
>  spots -- rot-11 --> *dazed*
>  hotel -- rot-7 --> *ovals*
>  bug -- rot-6 --> *ham*

Comment: The rule you found applies to not Rotting Words™ as well. Ex. rot13(oht ebg fvk vf unz).

Comment: @eyl327 But that's not the same rule - bug is only 3 letters long :) Will explain the non-Rotting words once I get out of a meeting in 30 mins!

Comment: That was... Fast

Comment: I see you mentioned rot13("jurer 'k' vf gur yratgu bs gur jbeq") already so you did get it originally. I will still like to see the explanation of the non-Rotting Words.

Comment: @eyl327 Updated, as promised :) Initially I had only spotted that these words did *not* follow the rule, not that they followed a slightly different one...! PS This is a fun question, must have been enjoyable finding all the examples and counter-examples :)

Comment: I wrote a program to find rotting words. Here's the list of all 199 I found: https://pastebin.com/M5qSZ6RA. To find the not rotting words I used the same program but added random shift amounts.