# What is a Disguised Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I like to call it a ***Disguised Word™***.
Find the rule that decides whether a word is a *Disguised Word™* or not, and why they are called so.

| Disguised Word™ | Non-Disguised Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| ARENA | FIELD |
| BANJO | CELLO |
| BEEF | MEAT |
| CRIB | BUNK |
| FUSION | BLEND |
| HAWK | EAGLE |
| HOTEL | LODGE |
| IBEX | GOAT |
| INGOT | BLOCK |
| JOLLY | HAPPY |
| MARRY | WED |
| SATIN | BURLAP |
| SHALE | ROCK |
| SPOT | FIND |
| TIMER | WATCH |

---

**CSV Version:**

```
Disguised Word™,Non-Disguised Word™
ARENA,FIELD
BANJO,CELLO
BEEF,MEAT
CRIB,BUNK
FUSION,BLEND
HAWK,EAGLE
HOTEL,LODGE
IBEX,GOAT
INGOT,BLOCK
JOLLY,HAPPY
MARRY,WED
SATIN,BURLAP
SHALE,ROCK
SPOT,FIND
TIMER,WATCH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a disguised word is one which

> forms another word after applying a [Rot(x) / Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) with an arbitrary shift. Non-disguised words do not.
>
> ```
> arena -> 17 -> river
> banjo -> 4 -> ferns
> beef -> 10 -> loop
> crib -> 9 -> lark
> fusion -> 6 -> layout
> hawk -> 8 -> pies
> hotel -> 7 -> ovals
> ibex -> 7 -> pile
> ingot -> 20 -> chain
> jolly -> 19 -> cheer
> marry -> 20 -> gulls
> satin -> 20 -> munch
> shale -> 19 -> latex
> spot -> 11 -> daze
> timer -> 7 -> aptly
> ```

They're called disguised words because

> The words act as a cipher text

Comment: Spot on!  
Hmm, that's not so great, I was working with [this list](http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_caps.txt) of over 58k words and had assumed it would be exhaustive.

Comment: Ah, so a Disguised Word is very similar to a [Rotting Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/97931/60644) then...

Comment: @KabirKanhaArora FWIW, when it comes to things like this I usually work with [this list](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words) of around 466k words. When in doubt, I double-check them in MW because admittedly it does contain some "words" which appear to be nonsense

Comment: @LukasRotter thanks! I've re-run my code with the new list (btw, 466k, crazy!) and updated two entries in the table to correct the puzzle, to account for obscure words which may otherwise seem to violate the rule. Btw, I was afraid this might happen, so I picked pairs that contained both fairly common words.